# Python file paths & filtering for specific extension only

Tags: python, json

The script I am using to produce the JSON file is below. What I would to know is if there is an easy way to use this script (since it is working) but to only create the items if the files have a .WAV extension?

If not, I can move the script to a parent directory, but then how would I need to modify the script to scan a sub-directory instead of the same directory the script resides in? Would that be the line with def path_ hierarchy(path) ?

I am open to whichever answer is easiest, but I am also trying to learn so if both questions could be answered it would be really cool, because I do want to understand the processes.

```
import os
import errno

def path_hierarchy(path):
    hierarchy = {
        'artist': os.path.basename(path),
        'album': 'Node 42177',
        'url': os.path.join("../audio/", os.path.basename(path)),
        'cover_art_url': '../album-art/Radio.jpg',
    }

    try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
            for contents in os.listdir(path)
        ]
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
            raise
        #hierarchy['type'] = 'file'

    return hierarchy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import json
    import sys

    try:
        directory = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        directory = "."

    print(json.dumps(path_hierarchy(directory), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: For any string, `s`, you can check `s.lower().endswith(wav)`

Comment: I don't see an s anywhere in the above code. Or do you mean that I should insert that? I am a beginner, where is the string specified? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Wherever you have a string with a filename, treat that as `s`. And my comment should have said `'wav'` not `wav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand the second option you proposed, but to answer the first option you could check each `contents` being generated in your `for contents in os.listdir(path)` for loop comprehension that it contains the `.WAV` extension.

Keeping with your setup, it would look like the following:

```
...
try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
            for contents in os.listdir(path)
            if '.WAV' in contents
        ]
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your second question but to answer your first question, I find the easiest way to check a file type is this:

```
try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
            for contents in os.listdir(path)
                if file.endswith('.wav'):
                    # do something
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module if you are use Python 3.  It makes using paths and files so much more straightforward.  (I've taken a few liberties just to show why Path is so much better than the `os` alternatives.

```
from pathlib import Path

cwd_ = Path.cwd()
parent_path = cwd_.parent

def path_hierarchy(path):
    p = Path(path)
    hierarchy = {
        'artist': p.stem,
        'album': 'Node 42177',
        'url': parent_path/"audio"/p.stem,
        'cover_art_url': parent_path/'album-art/Radio.jpg',
    }

    try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(contents)
            for contents in p.glob('*.mp3') ### YOUR EXTENSION HERE
        ]
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
            raise
        #hierarchy['type'] = 'file'

    return hierarchy
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this as well.